# Сумма последовательности простых чисел

Tags: c#, алгоритм, простые-числа

Вообщем задаче написать на c# программу, без массивов (коллекций), решающую задачу:

> Найти длину и значение суммы элементов последовательности простых чисел, в сумме
>   дающих простое число, меньшее 1000.

Можно описать хотя бы алгоритм, думаю смогу его закодить. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Да перебор, чего тут думать? Два цикла, внешний перебирает числа и копит сумму, внутренний проверяет на простоту.

Comment: Возможно я конечно, что-то не понимаю, но например, нашли простое число, добавляем его к сумме, но при этом сумма это тоже должно быть простое число, как проверить что последующее добавление нескольких простых чисел, в сумме даст тоже простое число?

Comment: Мне кажется, или ответ не единственный? Например, 2 и 3 это простые числа, в сумме дают простое число 5. Или 2, 3, 5 и 7 это простые числа, в сумме дают простое число 17.

Comment: Последовательных с первого?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну просто берём и проверяем всё на простоту по мере необходимости:

```js
function isPrime(x) {
  for (var q=2; q*q<=x; ++q) {
    if (!(x % q)) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

for (var x=2, s=0, l=0; s<1000; ++x) {
  if (isPrime(x)) {
    ++l;
    if (isPrime(s+=x)) {
      console.log(l, s);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: дальше корня смотреть нет смысла, n/2 - многовато, особенно на больших n

Comment: @rdorn, согласен, исправил. Впрочем, большими числами тут и не пахнет.

Answer (score 0):

Можно ограничиться проверкой нечётных делителей:

```
    public static bool OddIsPrime(int i)
    {
        for (int j = 3; j * j <= i; j += 2)
            if (i % j == 0)
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)  // Debug -> Myprojects.Property
    {
        int i, sum = 2, len = 1;

        Console.WriteLine("Последовательности простых чисел с простыми суммами до 1000:");
        Console.WriteLine("len = " + len + "    sum = " + sum);
        for (i = 3; sum < 1000; i += 2)
            if (OddIsPrime(i))
            {
                len++;
                if ((((sum += i) & 1) == 1) && OddIsPrime(sum))
                    Console.WriteLine("len = " + len + "    sum = " + sum);
            }
    }
```

Результат такой же:

```
Последовательности простых чисел с простыми суммами до 1000:
len = 1    sum = 2
len = 2    sum = 5
len = 4    sum = 17
len = 6    sum = 41
len = 12    sum = 197
len = 14    sum = 281
```